# what is the difference between branch from version by workspace and by latest version

Tags: tfs

If I've started making changes, and then realize that I should have branched first, i assumed that if I create a branch "from version by workspace" I would get a new branch with my workspace version in the branch.  But It doesn't seem to work that way so I'm now confused about the different options in branching "from version" with Team Foundation Server 2008.

Answer (score 7):

Intentionally I would agree with you, but branching by workspace means that if you, lets say, last checked out Changeset 107 and the latest Changeset is 109 and you branch by workspace the TFS takes Changeset 107 as the base for the new branch. Local changes are ignored in that case.

Best wishes,
Fabian